# Changing textContent in workday

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a Rate my professor Chrome extension that displays professor ratings on the workday. However, I am having some problems for access the specific span element by using getElementsByClassName.

Here is my code:

courses = document.getElementsByClassName('gwt-InlineLabel WG5F WF4F')
console.log(courses.textContent)

[Workday Sources Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j0hv.png)

Comment: getElementsByClassName() returns an array.

Comment: Thank you! I just realize that there could be more than one element with the same class names. However, when I am trying to access the element in the array, it still doesn't show up in the console.